# Android object to JSON

Tags: android, android-json

I'm making a simple mp3 player. I would like to save my main player object state when I'm rotating the device. So I have to serialize object, now I doing it in this way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(player);
```

But it doesn't work. Application crash. Message from monitor:

```
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 141482(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 194(3MB) LOS objects, 39% free, 11MB/19MB, paused 5.546ms total 79.570ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154295(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 191(3MB) LOS objects, 35% free, 12MB/19MB, paused 6.047ms total 69.778ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 154536(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 168(3MB) LOS objects, 40% free, 13MB/21MB, paused 5.992ms total 101.316ms
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 183709(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 179(4MB) LOS objects, 36% free, 13MB/21MB, paused 7.897ms total 89.325ms
```

Can you tell me how to do it in correct way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are Garbage Collection messages. Highly unlikely that this is the cause of the crash.

Comment: This messages shows only when i try make this Json. When i'm comment it app works and its disappears. But I have to make this Json and i dont know how ;)

Comment: Put the code in try-catch block. Show us the exception stacktrace.

Comment: There are no exception. It's just freeze

Comment: try putting the json part in another thread.. maybe it is working (you said app freezes!)